# ValueError: The truth value of array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, loops, numpy

I'm trying to iterate Numpy values, but I seem to be getting an error.

```
for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3]:
   ax.axvline(enter_pos, c ='g')
   ax.axvline(exit_pos, c = 'r')
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I know there are other answers on Stackover flow with this problem, but I have no idea what to do. The answers don't highlight how to change the code to accommodate a for loop, which is what has seem to have tripped me up.

I've tried:

```
ax in [ax1], ax in [ax2], ax in [ax3]

ax[ax1 & ax2 & ax3]
```

But nothing has worked yet.

Ideas?

*** Edit ***

Here is more of the code:

```
    ax1 = plt.subplot(311)
    data[[ticker[0], ticker[1]]].plot(ax = ax1)
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)

    ax2 = plt.subplot(312, sharex=ax1)
    results.spread.plot(ax=ax2, color='k')
    ax2.axhline(2, color='k')
    ax2.axhline(5, color='k')
    plt.ylabel('Spread')
    plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)

    ax3 = plt.subplot(313, sharex=ax1)
    results.portfolio_value.plot(ax=ax3, color='k')
    plt.ylabel('Portfolio Value')

    # Plot spread enter and exit markers
    enter_pos = results.index[results.buy_spread]
    exit_pos = results.index[results.sell_spread]

    for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3]:
        ax.axvline(enter_pos, c ='g')
        ax.axvline(exit_pos, c = 'r')

    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(16, 12)
```

*** EDIT 2 ***

I want to say the comment about the second loop is correct, but I still get the same error with this code:

```
for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3]:
  for pos in enter_pos:
    ax.axvline(enter_pos, c ='g')
    ax.axvline(exit_pos, c = 'r')
```

Comment: Can you post the _full_ traceback?  As is, it's hard to see exactly why the error is being thrown.  It looks like you're trying to iterate over matplotlib axes which doesn't have much to do with the exception you're seeing.  The exception probably has to do with `enter_pos` and `exit_pos`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`axvline` only support one number, you need a second loop:

```
for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3]:
    for pos in enter_pos:
        ax.axvline(pos, c ='g')
    for pos in exit_pos:
        ax.axvline(pos, c ='r')
```

but if the size of `enter_pos` is large it maybe slow. You can use `LineCollection` istead, here is an example:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import collections
from matplotlib import transforms

def axvlines(ax, x, **kw):
    from matplotlib import collections
    from matplotlib import transforms

    x = np.asanyarray(x)
    y0 = np.zeros_like(x)
    y1 = np.ones_like(x)        
    data = np.c_[x, y0, x, y1].reshape(-1, 2, 2)
    trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transAxes)
    lines = collections.LineCollection(data, transform=trans, **kw)
    ax.add_collection(lines)
```

You can use it as:

```
axvlines(enter_pos, colors="g")
axvlines(exit_pos, colors="r")
```

By using `axvlines()`, you can even create a colormap for the lines:

```
X = np.logspace(-1, 0, 50)
fig, ax = pl.subplots()
axvlines(ax, X, cmap="jet", array=np.linspace(0, 1, 50))
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: I want to say you're right, but I'm still getting an error with the second loop.

Comment: @Chef1075, you need change `enter_pos` to `pos`. and create another forloop for `exit_pos`, but if `enter_pos ` and `exit_pos` have many elements, it will be very slow. So I added another method that use `LineCollection`.